# how to select data from table which is a row data in another table

Tags: mysql

the exp_lab_mapping contains the entry

```
lab_id->cse05
exp_id->CSE0501
```

and I want to select the data from table CSE0501 by writing query

```
select * from (select exp_id from exp_lab_mapping where lab_id='cse05') as a;
```

but it's not giving me the data of CSE0501 instead it's giving output as

```
Output:-
----------
exp_id
CSE0501
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, you need to create a dynamic sql since, *if i correctly understood your problem*, you want to select records from which the name of the table is a row from table `exp_lab_mapping`. (*which is also a bad schema design*)

```
SET @sql = (SELECT exp_id FROM exp_lab_mapping WHERE lab_id = 'cse05');
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @sql);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bea9/1)